# Sampling Design Problem

Tags: sampling, experiment-design, biostatistics

I am comparing two types of areas, Intact forests and small patchy forests within agricultural areas (fragments).

I was supposed to conduct my sampling inside the Intact forest using the average of area of the total no. of fragments which is 10ha. However, I have made a miscalculation and conducted my sampling in only half of the area i.e., ~5ha.

This implies that I have sampled in 10ha in fragment sites and only in 5ha in the Intact forest.

I had sampled using camera traps using stratified random sampling. So my one sample will be images of animals from one camera trap. I have a total of 100 such sampling events.

I had planned on making generalised linear models from this data.

The fragments were divided longitudinally into two halves and then averaging the area of the halves. The total no. of fragments was 10, instead of using it as 10, I had used it as 20, which led me to obtain the 5ha.

Comment: Welcome to the site. It is certainly possible to do good analysis with stratified sampling; it is also possible that the way you did it is going to lead to a mess. It will depend on the details of your sampling and whether the portion you sampled is different from the portion you didn't and other features of the data.

Comment: Thank you! Can you please tell me how I can reclarify the question?

Comment: It would help to describe the statistical analysis you planned to do and to explain its objectives.  It would also be useful to know how those 5 ha sub-portions were selected.

Comment: I have edited it, does it sound better?